# Running pytest from mounted container in azure pipeline: permission denied error

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, pytest

I'm trying to run pytest within a container in an azure pipeline, in a way that makes the result visible in the pipeline overview.
My Dockerfile is a simpel one to run a python script. The working directory is /app.

My pipeline looks as follow:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    arguments: '-t test:$(Build.BuildId)'
    
- script: |
    docker run --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/app \
              --entrypoint /bin/bash test:$(Build.BuildId) \
              -c "pytest"
  displayName: 'tests'
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/test-*.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'Publish test results for Python $(python.version)'
```

Notice that the working directory is bound to the /app folder, which should make the test-output.xml file available for the next step.

Pytest runs succesfully in the pipeline, but it gives the following error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, the  user used to execute pythontest command in the docker environment does not have permission to access the /app folder.

You can refer to the following methods to grant the permission to the user.

1.Change to use the Root user in the dockerfile with the commnad: `USER root`

For example:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04 AS builder
USER root
# install the prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

# copy in the requirements
COPY requirements.txt /srv/requirements.txt
COPY requirements-dev.txt /srv/requirements-dev.txt
```

2.Use the chmod command to grant the permission of the folder to the current user.

For example:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04 AS builder
RUN chmod -R 777 /app

...
```

Comment: Cool thanks I'll try this. Can you explain a bit more though? Because in the container I can write to the folder if it is not mounted using the --mount command. The permission error only occurs when the folder is mounted. With these mounted folders, how are the file permissions managed? Is it about the user executing the container (on the host), or the user operation within the container?

Comment: It should be related to the  user operation within the container. And may I know if the method can give you some help?

Comment: But it cannot only be related to operation within the container, because when the folder is mounted it will write also to the host, so there has to also be some host-level permission checking involved, right? I'll try to see if this work later today.

Comment: Yes. you are right. But from the error, the error exists when writing content to the path in container env. You can check the permission in the container first. I think it could resolve the issue. If you get any issue when writing to host, you can check host level permission.

Comment: @user2520938 Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you need any help